# How to Split camel case sentence in ts_vector (PosgreSQL)?

Tags: sql, postgresql, full-text-search, token

When I write a query
`SELECT to_tsvector('simple','logDescription');`. The output is:

```
  to_tsvector     
--------------------
 'logdescription':1
```

I want output like the below: Is there a way to achieve the below outcome?

```
 to_tsvector     
--------------------
'log': 1 'Description':1
```